# Не собираются scss в gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, frontend, scss

gulp собирает js и шаблоны но не компилирует стили в папку build, хотя выводится сообщение о том, что начата и завершена работа с задачей стилей.В чем может быть проблема?

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    csslint = require('gulp-csslint'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    cache = require('gulp-cache'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    cleanCss = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    cmq = require('gulp-merge-media-queries'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    minifyHtml = require('gulp-minify-html'),
    browserify = require('gulp-browserify');


// Browser sync server for live reload
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init(
        ["build/css/*.css", "build/js/*.js", "build/templates/*.html"], {
            proxy:  "localhost:8000"
        });
});

gulp.task('images', function(){
    return gulp.src('src/static/img/*')
        .pipe(cache(imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 3, progressive: true, interlaced: true })))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/img/'))
        .pipe(notify('images task finished'))
});

gulp.task('styles', function(){
    return gulp.src(['src/static/scss/*.scss'])
        .pipe(plumber({
            handleError: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                this.emit('end');
            }
        }))
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(cmq({log:true}))
        .pipe(csslint())
        .pipe(csslint.formatter())
        .pipe(cleanCss())

        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'))
        .pipe(notify('styles task finished'))
});

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    return gulp.src(['src/static/js/*.js'])
        .pipe(plumber({
            handleError: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                this.emit('end');
            }
        }))
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
        .pipe(browserify())
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'))
        .pipe(notify('scripts task finished'))
});
gulp.task('templates',function(){
    return gulp.src(['src/templates/*.html'])
        .pipe(plumber({
            handleError: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                this.emit('end');
            }
        }))
        .pipe(minifyHtml())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/templates'))
        .pipe(notify('templates task finished'))
});
gulp.task('build_static', function(){
    gulp.watch('src/static/js/*.js',['scripts']);
    gulp.watch('src/static/scss/*.scss',['styles']);
    gulp.watch('src/templates/*.html',['templates']);
    gulp.watch('src/static/img/*',['images']);
});

// Run django server
gulp.task('runServer', function(cb) {
    var cmd = spawn('python', ['src/manage.py', 'runserver'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
    cmd.on('close', function(code) {
        console.log('runServer exited with code ' + code);
        cb(code);
    });
});

// Default task
gulp.task('default', function() {
    runSequence(['build_static', 'browser-sync'], ['runServer']);
});
```

Comment: в `'src/static/scss/*.scss'` что-то лежит?

Comment: Файлы лежат в 'src/static/scss/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Компилируемые файлы стилей не должны начинаться с _